# Java drawing with delay

Tags: java, graphics

I'm trying to visualize various graph-algorithms. I want to make it so, that after every 2 seconds the graph get updated and gets repainted. I have tried using the Thread.sleep() method but it just freezes the GUI and then after a while is done with the complete algorithm.

(I am fairly new to Java so don't be to harsh with the code)
The Code in question:

```
else if(ae.getSource() == fordFulkersonButton){
    dinicButton.setEnabled(false);
    edmondsKarpButton.setEnabled(false);
    gtButton.setEnabled(false);

    if(checkbox.isEnabled()){
        fordFulkersonButton.setEnabled(false);

        while(!fordFulkerson.getIsDone()){
            flowNetwork = fordFulkerson.algoFF(flowNetwork);
            popupText.setVisible(true);

            Integer i = new Integer(flowNetwork.getCurrentFlow());
            String s = i.toString();
            popupText.setText("Aktueller Fluß: "+s);
            graphDrawer.setFlowNetwork(flowNetwork);
            this.showFrame();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(2 * 1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        Integer in = new Integer(flowNetwork.getCurrentFlow());
        String st = in.toString();
        popupText.setText("Algorithmus is beendet mit Fluss: "+st);
    }
    flowNetwork = fordFulkerson.algoFF(flowNetwork);
    popupText.setVisible(true);
    Integer i = new Integer(flowNetwork.getCurrentFlow());
    String s = i.toString();

    if(fordFulkerson.getIsDone()){
        popupText.setText("Algorithmuss beednet mit maximalen Fluß: "+s);
    }else{
        popupText.setText("Aktueller Fluß: "+s);
    }
    graphDrawer.setFlowNetwork(flowNetwork);
    this.showFrame();
}
```

Comment: Use a Swing Timer, not `Thread.sleep(...)` since the latter puts your entire app to sleep.

Comment: `Thread.sleep` means that your main thread sleeps with your GUI. You basically want to create a Thread or Runnable which does the painting job.

Answer (score 0):

Doing huge amounts of work in a UI thread freezes the UI. If you want to do animations or complex work, use [a worker thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) or a [Swing timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

You must not call `Thread.sleep()` in Swing UI code. Instead, you need to think like an animator: Show one frame of the animation at a time. Some external source will call your code to show the next frame. The external source is the Swing timer. Your code draws the next frame and returns. That way, you never block the UI thread for long.

Google for "swing animation". Interesting results are:

- http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/Timerbasedanimation.htm
- http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/animation/

Comment: I had a look into Swing timer, but I don't really understand how to use it in my case!

Comment: You need to think like an animator: Show one frame of the animation at a time. See my edits.

Comment: I had a look at the edits. And i must say that it becomes a lot clearer.